# Session time out java

Tags: java, http, session, jsessionid

This is regarding http session.

I'm having two applications which are running on two applications servers in two different ports. I login to a one application and then open a new tab from the same browser and login to the other application. Then what happen is it will timeout the first application's session.

In both applications http session is used wen login and logout.

What could be the root cause for the above scenario.

Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually try adding cookies

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   if (request.getParameter("JSESSIONID") != null) {
    Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", request.getParameter("JSESSIONID"));
    response.addCookie(userCookie);
   } else {
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId);
    response.addCookie(userCookie);
   }
```

Comment: Good answer - I'm not sure of whether they were not understanding why the problem was occurring - or how to fix it - you provided a good fix - wouldnt this also accept possibly any session id though?

Comment: Yes its like a hot fix I used on my testing intranet deployment. Would be silly to push into production, but in my case the domain names were different for the 2 applications, the problem didn't persist

Comment: Good reason - understood!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I did was I requested a one cookie with a different name apart from the JSESSIONID and used JSESSIONID for the other application. Then it did resolve the problem that I faced. But I will try your solution also.

Answer (score 3):

If both applications are the exact same application and their both running on the same server, but different ports - one session cookie is invalidating the other session cookie, I run into it all the time so if you want to accomplish what you're trying to do you can open one session in a "private" window and this will keep the sessions from being invalidated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. 
The thing is both applications are not running on the same application servers. When the both applications are running on the same server, it's correct what you've mentioned here. 
But in my case two applications are running on two different application servers an on two different ports. So in this case the same session cannot be invalidated. Because the two different servers are sending two different cookies with the same name of JSESSIONID but with different session IDs. So the sessions cannot be overridden. So that was my concern no this problem.